# How to determine subtype of a type parameter in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-parameter

```
class S
class A extends S
class B extends S

class ClassWithTypeParameter[+T]

val a: ClassWithTypeParameter[S] = new ClassWithTypeParameter[A]
```

How can one determine the type of the subclass used for the type parameter of value a ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot because of **type erasure**. However, I would argue that your attempt to do this is formed from a mis-understanding.

- The point of a type system is so that the compiler can reason more powerfully about the correctness of your program.
- In a static type system, each reference has a *type* which cannot be changed

In your program, there is one reference, `a` and the type of this reference is `ClassWithTypeParameter[S]`. That. Is. All. The compiler can know what can be done with this reference. The types are there purely for the compiler. The fact that, at *runtime*, `a` was assigned to a value which was a `ClassWithTypeParameter[A]` is irrelevant.

---

One possible way of doing this *to some approximation* (limited by erasure) is to use **manifests** (called something else in 2.10):

```
class ClassWithTypeParameter[+T: Manifest] { def erasure = manifest[T].erasure }
```

Then you can call `erasure` which will get you a `java.lang.Class` back. As I said, this is limited. A *class* is not the same thing as a *type* and there is no way to distinguish, for example, `ClassWithTypeParameter[List[Int]]` from `ClassWithTypeParameter[List[Double]]`

Comment: But it is possible to use the manifests to distinguish between `CWTP[List[Int]]` and `CWTP[List[Double]]`—just not if you take the erasure.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a bad idea (like most uses of reflection) but it works:

```
class ClassWithTypeParameter[+T: Manifest] {
  def paramIs[V: Manifest] = manifest[T] == manifest[V]
}
```

Which gives us:

```
scala> val a: ClassWithTypeParameter[S] = new ClassWithTypeParameter[A]
a: ClassWithTypeParameter[S] = ClassWithTypeParameter@6493c09c

scala> a.paramIs[A]
res0: Boolean = true

scala> a.paramIs[S]
res1: Boolean = false

scala> a.paramIs[B]
res2: Boolean = false
```

And:

```
scala> val i = new ClassWithTypeParameter[List[Int]]
i: ClassWithTypeParameter[List[Int]] = ClassWithTypeParameter@260702ee

scala> i.paramIs[List[Int]]
res3: Boolean = true

scala> i.paramIs[List[Double]]
res4: Boolean = false
```

You could write similar `paramSubtypeOf` and `paramSupertypeOf` methods using `Manifest`'s `<:<` and `>:>`.

In Scala 2.10 (Milestone 4 or later) there's [a much more flexible way](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.runtime.package) to get the type:

```
class ClassWithTypeParameter[+T: TypeTag] {
  def paramType = reflect.runtime.universe.typeTag[T].tpe
}
```

Now you could write things like `a.paramType.parents` to get the immediate supertypes, etc.